# What is registry and how do we use to register our assets / chaincode in hyper-ledger fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to understand about registry, like what is registry, why do we need to store Assets and Chaincodes in registry, where does registry gets stored.

Comment: Can you elaborate a  bit, what do you mean?

Comment: In simple words, can we know what is registry and how is it used in Hyper-ledger fabric? - @ArtemBarger

Comment: There is no such logic entity in Hyperledger Architecture as registry, hence I'm wondering what exactly you are referring to...

Answer (score 0):

Firt of all, the chaincode (or smart contracts) and the assets are two different things.

- Chaincode: the code that you will execute/invoke. This code is the same in all the nodes, i.e. each node of the network has installed the same chaincode.
- Assets: you digitize the assets using transactions that are governed by smart contracts.

On the other hand, how it works:

- Ledger: the Ledger stores all the transactions. The ledger is comprised of a blockchain (‘chain’) to store the immutable, sequenced record in blocks. Each peer maintains a copy of the ledger.
- State Database: maintains the current state. It represents the latest values for all keys ever included in the chain transaction log. Chaincode invocations execute transactions against the current state data.